# What is the Correct Definition of Cocone in Category Theory?

Tags: category-theory

I've been reading some basic category theory, and am slightly confused about the definition of a cocone. I've been looking at the notes here - https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~jg352/pdf/CategoryTheoryNotes.pdf - specifically pages 15.

> A cone with apex $A$ over diagram $D: J \to C$ is defined to be the
>   object $A$ with a set of maps $\mu_j: A \to D(j)$ s.t. for each
>   morphism $\alpha: j \to j'$ in $J$, the following diagram commutes: $$
>  \begin{array}{ccc}  &A & \\ \swarrow&&\searrow\\
>  D(j)&\rightarrow&D(j') \end{array} $$

I'm fine with this, but I'm not quite sure how a cocone is defined.

My question is: ***which of the following two definitions is correct?***

> **Defn 1**: Just reverse all the arrows above, so under the map to the opposite category cocones go tocones and vice versa. Note that the
>   diagram in the opposite category then has to become a contravariant
>   functor (as arrows in the diagram are reversed).
>
> **Defn 2**: Same as the definition of the cone, but the object $A$ now lies "underneath" the diagram, and the triangle that has to commute is
>   $$ \begin{array}{ccc} D(j)&\rightarrow&D(j')\\ \searrow&&\swarrow\\
>  &A& \end{array} $$
>
> which isn't just the same as reversing all the arrows in the triangle
>   above.

The second definition seems to be what the notes suggest when they say a cocone is a "cone under D", but this seems less nice to me as it doesn't mesh nicely with the opposite category. But I don't see a nice way to define the dual of a cone without having to change the definition of the diagram in the opposite category (and make it into a contravariant functor).

I guess my question is equivalent to:

**"do colimits always become limits when you go to the opposite category?"**.

If the first definition is correct then yes, if the second definition is correct then I don't think so in general.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Shouldn't a cocone be called just a ne?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding the duality between limits and colimits, what you're overlooking is that you can also take the opposite of the *index* category as well.

It may be helpful to observe that cones and cocones are morphisms in the functor category $C^J$. If $J$ is the index category, then there is the 'diagonal' embedding $ \Delta : C \to C^J $ that sends every object to the constant functor.

Then, for a diagram $J \to C$, a cone with apex $A$ is simply a natural transformation $\Delta(A) \to F$, whereas a cocone is a natural transformation $F \to \Delta(A)$.

And note that the $(C^J)^\circ \cong (C^\circ)^{J^\circ}$.

In fact, if $C$ has all $J$-indexed limits (respectively colimits), then $\lim$ (respectively $\mathop{\mathrm{colim}}$) is the right (respectively left) adjoint of $\Delta$.

Comment: Ahh, so to clarify, if we have a limit of $J$ and go to the opposite category, we get a colimit of $J^\circ$?

Comment: @ECG: That is correct.